# HSQLDB and Liquibase, Table already exists: DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, hsqldb, liquibase

I am trying to implement unit tests with liquibase and HSQLDB.
Everything works fine. but for some reason when liquibase try to apply the change log on the database i get:

> ```
> INFO 14:19 14/06/14:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
> INFO 14:19 14/06/14:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
> 2014-06-14 14:19:03,923 [DEBUG] [NewPooledConnection,handleThrowable(),430] - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@281fb795 handling a throwable.
> java.sql.SQLException: Table already exists: DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK in statement [CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK]
> at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
> at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
> at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
> at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.execute(NewProxyStatement.java:1006)
> ```

I cant wrap my head around why this might happen.

The context is raised once. and by no means i see that table being created before...

As well HSQLDB runs in memory. so there is a new instance..

Any ideas?
Here is my context and maven plugin configuration":

> ```
> repository.connectionString = jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
> repository.driver = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
> repository.username = SA
> repository.password = 
> repository.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
> repository.hibernate.showSQL = true
> repository.hibernate.onStartup = verify
>
>
>
> public com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
>     com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
>     ds.setDriverClass(REPOSITORY_DRIVER);
>     ds.setJdbcUrl(REPOSITORY_CONNTION_STRING);
>     ds.setUser(REPOSITORY_USERNAME);
>     ds.setPassword(REPOSITORY_PASSWORD);
>     ds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
>     ds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);
>     ds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
>     ds.setMaxStatements(50);
>     ds.setMinPoolSize(5);
>     return ds;
> }
> @Bean
> @Autowired
> public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalSessionFactoryBean annotationSessionFactoryBean) {
>     return new HibernateTransactionManager(annotationSessionFactoryBean.getObject());
> }
> @Bean
> @Autowired
> public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(ComboPooledDataSource dataSource) {
>     LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
>     localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
>     localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "X.Y.Z" });
>     localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
>     return localSessionFactoryBean;
> }   
> @Bean
> @Autowired
> public SpringLiquibase liquibae(ComboPooledDataSource dataSource){
>     SpringLiquibase springLiquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
>     springLiquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
>     springLiquibase.setContexts("dev,test");
>     springLiquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db/db.changelog-master.xml");   
>     return springLiquibase;
> }
> private Properties hibernateProperties() {
>     Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
>     hibernateProperties.setProperty("dialect", REPOSITORY_HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
>     hibernateProperties.setProperty("show_sql", REPOSITORY_HIBERNATE_SHOWSQL);
>     hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", REPOSITORY_HIBERNATE_ONSTARTUP);
>     return hibernateProperties;
> }
> ```

maven:

> ```
>  <plugin>
>     <!-- current version -->
>     <groupId>fr.avianey.mojo</groupId>
>     <artifactId>hsqldb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0.0</version>
>     <!-- call start and stop -->
>     <executions>
>         <execution>
>             <id>start-hsqldb</id>
>             <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>start</goal>
>             </goals>
>         </execution>
>         <execution>
>             <id>stop-hsqldb</id>
>             <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>stop</goal>
>             </goals>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
> </plugin>
> ```

Comment: What version of liquibase are your running?

Comment: Thanks. I think the answer is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233037/org-hsqldb-hsqlexception-user-lacks-privilege-or-object-not-found-databasechan You need to call ChangeLogHistoryServiceFactory.getInstance().reset() where you clear out your database

Comment: I'll check it out eventually, moved to embedded mysql instance for my integration tests. but i most defiantly prefer the lighter version.

Comment: do you use different changelog files (e.g. copys in different folders) on the same Database?