# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK

Tags: testing, hsqldb, liquibase

How can this happen.

Isn't liquibase supposed to create this table for itself...

This is an in memory database created for unit testing.

> ```
> public void setUp(String contexts) {
>     try {
>         ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor = new FileSystemResourceAccessor();
>         Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
>         holdingConnection = getConnectionImpl();
>         HsqlConnection hsconn = new HsqlConnection(holdingConnection);
>         liquibase = new Liquibase(CHANGE_LOG, resourceAccessor, hsconn);
>         liquibase.dropAll();
>         liquibase.update(contexts);
>         hsconn.close();
>     } catch (Exception ex) {
>         LOG.error("Error during database initialization", ex);
>         throw new RuntimeException("Error during database initialization", ex);
>     }
> }
> private Connection getConnectionImpl() throws SQLException {
>     return DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
> }
> ```

Same as in the hsqldb examples

The stacktrace:

> ```
>  2014-06-15 21:50:34,195 [DEBUG] [PropertySourcesPropertyResolver,getProperty(),103] - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
>  2014-06-15 21:50:34,195 [DEBUG] [CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate,loadContext(),93] - Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key [[MergedContextConfiguration@5879ff89 testClass = SampleUnitTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class context.RepositoryContextConfig, class context.repoConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
>  2014-06-15 21:50:34,198 [DEBUG] [AbstractBeanFactory,doGetBean(),249] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
>  INFO 21:50 15/06/14: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
>  INFO 21:50 15/06/14: liquibase: Dropping Database Objects in schema: PUBLIC.PUBLIC
>  INFO 21:50 15/06/14: liquibase: Creating database history table with name: PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG
> INFO 21:50 15/06/14: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
>    2014-06-15 21:51:17,842 [ERROR] [HsqlDatabase,setUp(),41] - Error during database initialization
>  liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException:      liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL select count(*) from      PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK: user lacks privilege or object not found:   DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
> at   liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:214)
> at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:153)
> at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:182)
> at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:174)
> at context.HsqlDatabase.setUp(HsqlDatabase.java:38)
> at context.SampleUnitTest.onlyOnce(SampleUnitTest.java:19)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>  Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL select count(*) from PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK: user lacks privilege or object not found: DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
> at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.isDatabaseChangeLogLockTableInitialized(StandardLockService.java:121)
> at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.init(StandardLockService.java:95)
> at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:187)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That error on hsqldb usually means the table doesn't exist. The "does the databasechangelog table exist" caching mechanism can become incorrect if you drop the databasechangelog table after it has been checked.

There is a fix for that in an the upcoming liquibase 3.3 version, but for now if you add `ChangeLogHistoryServiceFactory.getInstance().reset()` where you clear out your database it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error can occur, when your connection is closed or invalid.

I get the same error when using Hsqldb-2.3.2 with a connection pool (like dbcp) and a validationQuery. Once a validationQuery has invalidated the connection the error is thrown on next database access.

Since your in a test, this will not be your Problem, but you could debug the connection and see if it is open at the time of error.